# MongoDB - ASp.net - Questions

Tags: .net, mongodb, asp.net-mvc-2, hosting, nosql

I’am starting a personal web project. Which I hope it grows fast. It will do a lot of text inserts and searches in this project. So it seems MongoDB a good option. But of course there is not a hosting of asp.net and mongoDB. Also I do not want to expend a lot of money, at the beginning.

So I have the idea of contract https://mongohq.com/pricing, which is free, this serves me for developing and testing of beta versions. And contract an ASP.Net Hosting like GoDaddy or any good hosting for less tha 30USD a month. Once I launch my site, of course I will change my plan of MongoHQ to a pay one. 6 month later if the visits are increasing, and the business it’s going good of course i will start paying good hosting cloud like RackSpace servers.

The only thing I´m worry is the latency between MongoHQ and the asp.net hosting. Do you think this is a good idea?  How can I test the latency between hostings? Can you give me any hint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using free hosting services, then just plug it all in and try it out.  You can measure the response time on the web server side.

Comment: Good Idea. But I been reading and perhaps the best idea is a micro instance on EC2. Those seems cheap.